# When should the playing 11 be decided in a cricket match?

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating, strategy, team-dynamics

I often see a thing in the cricket match broadcast, that the captains are on the pitch with a match official(commentator) and the toss would be done. Then the two captains will talk about the pitch condition, weather and mainly about playing eleven(who are all in and out).

Then the playing 11 from the squad will be listed.(As I saw in the match television broadcast).

I want to know,

- When should the playing 11 be decided in a cricket match?
- Is it possible to make any changes in the playing eleven after the
  toss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Law 1 (The Players)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-1-the-players/)

> #### 2. Nomination of players
>
> Each captain shall nominate his players in writing to one of the
> umpires **before the toss**. No player may be changed after the nomination
> without the consent of the opposing captain.

So the captain has to decide the playing eleven before the toss. Normally the playing eleven is not changed once it is nominated in writing. But in exception case if a caption wants to change the playing eleven he has to take consent of the opposing captain **before** the toss.

From [Wikipedia - Toss (cricket)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toss_%28cricket%29):

> Half an hour before the start of play, the two captains convene and exchange team selection sheets. These list the composition of each side, **which cannot be changed for the duration of the match**.

Now the match includes the toss too<sup>*</sup>. So the playing XI can not be changed after the toss.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toss_%28cricket%29): If the match is abandoned at any time *after* the toss, it stands as a **match played**. If a match is abandoned *before* the toss, it is **not** considered to have been played at all.</sub>

Comment: Substitutions are allowed in the case of injury, right?

Comment: @BenMiller - Absolutely allowed with the permission of the umpire.

Comment: `if a caption wants to change the playing eleven he has to take consent of the opposing captain`, when? after the match started? just for clearing the doubt :)

Comment: @SportsFan - No. **Before** the match is started. After the match is started they can use substitutes only. They can't replace the player.

Comment: After the toss, the playing eleven can be changed with the consent of the opposing captain, Is it?

Comment: But, this `after the toss` matter is not mentioned in the law!

Comment: `Is it possible to make any changes in the playing eleven after the toss?` is a part of the question.